# dc3dd, why tab completion doesn't work?

Tags: dd, autocomplete

On Slackware 15.

Using dd I do

`dd if=/home/myuser/my..TAB` and complete dir path after pressing tab

using dc3dd I did

`dc3dd if=/home/myuser/my..TAB` and nothing happen.

Why?

I have tried with rlwrap but nothing change

```
complete -p dd
```

said

```
bash: complete: dd: no completion specification
```

and

```
complete -p dc3dd

bash: complete: dc3dd: no completion specification
```

Comment: The TAB completion normally works for simple file name arguments. Probably your shell has some extension to know how to complete arguments of the `dd` command. It probably does not know that `dc3dd` has the same type of arguments. Do you use `bash`? Then show the output of `complete -p dd`.

Answer (score 1):

Your shell needs to be aware of the syntax of command line options, which is why they ship with extensive autocompletion scripts to give you the comfort you're used to.

It seems the shell you're using isn't aware of `dc3dd` (me neither), so that's why it doesn't know that it can complete filenames after `if=`. You could probably write your own completion that is an adjusted version of the script used to complete `dd` arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe one way is to modify `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/dd`, at the end, try replace `complete -F _dd dd` by `complete -F _dd dd dc3dd`

Comment: Give me error "function dd not found"